# Powershell for each loop wait for output

Tags: powershell, loops, wait

I am stumped with this one. I am trying to count OS types on various domains and output the count and computers. This way we can get a list of computers that need to be upgraded. However when I search for server 2012 computers it doesn't output the list of computers until two OS versions later and adds them to the server 2019 list. It works fine with all other OS versions.

[image: powershell output]

Is there a way to wait for the output before continuing the loop?

This is my code:

```
$cutoff = (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)
$OSlist = '2003', '2008', '2012', '2016', '2019', 'xp', '7', '8', '10'

foreach ($OS in $OSlist) {
    $OScount = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'LastLogonDate -gt $cutoff' -Properties Operatingsystem | Where-Object OperatingSystem -like "*$($OS)*" | measure | Select-Object -ExpandProperty count
    write-host "There are $($OScount) $($OS) computers"
    Get-ADComputer -Filter 'LastLogonDate -gt $cutoff' -Properties lastlogondate,operatingsystem | Where-Object OperatingSystem -like "*$($OS)*"  | Select-Object name,operatingsystem,lastlogondate
    
}
```

I have tried the following after searching for similar issues as well but that gave me some weird output of the jobs running:

```
$cutoff = (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)
$OSlist = '2003', '2008', '2012', '2016', '2019', 'xp', '7', '8', '10', '11'

foreach ($OS in $OSlist) {
    Start-Job -Name OScount -ScriptBlock {
        $OScount = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'LastLogonDate -gt $cutoff' -Properties Operatingsystem | Where-Object OperatingSystem -like "*$($OS)*" | measure | Select-Object -ExpandProperty count
        write-host "There are $($OScount) $($OS) computers"
        Get-ADComputer -Filter 'LastLogonDate -gt $cutoff' -Properties lastlogondate,operatingsystem | Where-Object OperatingSystem -like "*$($OS)*"  | Select-Object name,operatingsystem,lastlogondate
    }
    Wait-Job -Name OScount
}
```

Comment: On your first code snippet, the one that is not using `Start-Job`, try adding `Out-Host` at the end of the last line ( the one with `Get-ADComputer .... | Where-Object ... | Select-Object... | Out-Host`. I think that should give you what you want.

Comment: Yes that did work sorry! Do you want to post as an answer or shall I?

Comment: Yes, I really encourage people to put answers in as *answers* rather than comments. that way, the OP can mark it as answered and we don't waste our time looking at it! And it helps people who want to know the answer find the solution too. Comments are really to get more info or comment on the question itself (e.g. formatting), not provide solutions.

Comment: You know if you're not interested on the 0 computers result you could use `Group-Object OperatingSystem` on all the computers. That would give you a better perspective I think